# Tefillin shel yad wrapping custom by Tur

Tags: tefilin, tur

What method of tying tefillin shel yad for the hand suggested by Jacob ben Asher? The palm itself is of interest. I know about three turns on the middle finger. And the rest of hand? Like modern Ashkenazi in the form of a letter Shin? Also interested method of wrapping by Joel Sirkish (Bach).

Comment: I looked up siman 27: seif 8 and only saw that he holds 3 wrappings around finger ,and the Bach had no comment on this . However, if you are interested in seeing 18 different customs of how the wrapping of the finger and hand looks see Nitei Gavriel

Comment: do the pictures on this page and the following ones help? https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&st=&pgnum=626